# Keep the sum of numbers to a constant while making sure that each has a minimum value

Tags: javascript, math, underscore.js

I have an object with just numbers as values whose sum cannot exceed 100%. However, I want that each number has to have a minimum amount (let's say 5%); this basically means that, if a number in the array is 0, it is set to 5% and the amount is then distributed among all the other numbers which are greater than 0.

Obviously, one problem is that this could lead to situations in which a number was originally 6% and then it is actually reduced below the minimum.

Currently, my solution is this (with [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org)):

```
var numbers         = //this is the object,
    adjustedNumbers = {},
    // _.objFilter here is just like _.filter, but returns an object instead
    // of an array, retaining the key-value pairs
    zeroValues      = _.objFilter(numbers, function(num){ return num == 0 });
    greaterThanTen  = _.objFilter(numbers, function(num){ return num >= 10 });

    _.each(greaterThanTen, function(ratio, key){
        adjustedRangeRatio[key] = ratio - (_.size(zeroValues) / _.size(greaterThanTen)) * 5;
    });

    _.each(zeroValues, function(value, key){
          zeroValues[key] = 5;
    }

    _.extend(adjustedRangeRatio, zeroValues);
```

This works but, well, it is extremely ugly. I am sure there is a better, cleaner, more extensible way to do this.

Comment: What does happen to values between 0 and 5 percent?

Comment: Why can't you distribute according to their values. i.e., larger number gets deducted from a higher value and lower number gets deducted from a lower value.

Comment: Shouldn't it be that if the value is _less_ than the _minimum_ (say 5%) then it is set to 5% and the other values _over_ the _minimum_ are _reduced_ accordingly to ensure the total is 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a number was originally 6% and then it is actually reduced below the minimum.

You can try to reduce only the fraction that is above 5%.

```
var numbers = {…},
    adjusted = {};

var min = 5,
    sum = 0,
    count = 0,
    below = 0,
    belowCount = 0;
_.each(numbers, function(k, num) {
    sum += num;
    count++;
    if (num < min) {
        below += num;
        belowCount++;
    }
});
var aim = sum - min * count;
if (aim < 0)
    throw "Too many values, giving every the minimum would exceed sum";
var overMin = sum - below - (count-belowCount) * min,
    ratio = aim / overMin;
_.each(numbers, function(key, num) {
    if (num <= min)
        adjusted[key] = min;
    else
        adjusted[key] = min + (num - min) * ratio;
});
```

Comment: Thank you Bergi. I had to refactor your code a smidge but it did what I needed. I had hoped there was a *cleaner* way to do this, but this is certainly better than what I had.

Comment: Yeah, the general idea might be easier to formulate if Underscore did provide a `map` that does work on objects. Then one could do `b = map(numbers, (x)->x-5); a = map(b, (x)->max(x,0)); ratio = sum(b)/sum(a); adjusted = map(a, (x)->x*ratio+5)`

Comment: Thanks. Interesting use of `map`.